# After deleting the records from recycle bin does it resides in your org some where else?

Tags: apex, data

I have created one account and then i deleted it.

Its in recycle bin and then i run the following code and i got the list size as 1.

```
list<Account> acc = new list<Account>();

acc = [select id , name from Account where isDeleted = true ALL ROWS];

System.debug('------------  count \t'+acc.size());
```

After i cleared my recycle bin and re-run the code it still showing the list size as 1 . Please give some info on this thanks.

Comment: Take a look at this post - sounds like you are experiencing something similar?http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/20665/the-netherworld-of-deleted-records-not-in-recycle-bin

Comment: Ya but here am deleting the account record only

Comment: Yeah - but I think all deletes go into some nether world where they have been submitted for delete, so you can't retrieve them, but need a batch to run to actually delete them from SF database...

Comment: Ya let me check my org tomorrow or some time